# Is their a way to train my body out of being allergic (to pollen)?

Tags: allergen, pollen, hay-fever, seasonal-allergies, allergen-immunotherapy

*Disclaimer: if this is off-topic here, just let me know. This seemed like the right SE to ask it on.*

I get pretty bad hay fever in the spring/summer. Running nose, itching eyes, the whole thing. I know there are methods to limit your pollen exposure/symptoms, and there are of course drugs that can help, but I'm wondering if it's possible to train your body out of being allergic to pollen completely. Or to anything, for that matter.

I did some research, but was only able to find tips on reducing exposure. The closest I came was an [experiment](http://www.steadyhealth.com/topics/overcoming-allergies-is-possible), but it doesn't tell me how to get used to pollen in a home environment, where it's everywhere (it's also talking about severe allergies, which I do not have - don't worry, there is no risk of death here).

**Can I somehow get my body 'used' to pollen?** How?